# How to indent some text after a list item without regarding it as a list item in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

For example:

```
1. item1
    indented item, but not a list (1)
2. item2
3. item3

    indented item, with a blank line before and after (2)

4. item4, continue the list
```

How to produce (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the additional rows using Shift+Enter, and then indent them using Shift+Tab

Here is an example Doc: https://goo.gl/ifQEEp

Comment: Thanks! That shift+enter is amazing. I cannot tell the difference between tab and shift+tab, tho.